# VBA - DatePart/Month name for Jan to Dec count in table

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I would like to create an Access report with all of the Customer Types with 12 additional columns for January to December, showing the count of Survey_DateSurveyed in each month. I've started making a query and I've discoved DatePart and MonthName function but I'm clueless on what to do!  Is this a query job or VBA? I've added a couple of images of the start I've made but it's not doing what I was hoping (there's only 10 records in the database so far). Thanks in advance :)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hl548.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXE8N.png

Comment: Nope neither place. I thought I could just post a question up :S

Comment: Use the _crosstab_ query wizard.

Comment: Yep, you can just post a question up.  Just that the company I work for owns Bridgfords which is one of your field names. :).  To get the month name for a date use `MonthName(Month([Survey_DateSurveyed]))` and then crosstab as @Gustav suggests.

Comment: Please show attempted SQL and *what you were hoping*.

Comment: Thank you both, the Crosstab fixed it